# Trakt.tv JSON feed for Homepage

Tags: json, api

Hi i just start to create a small widget for trakt.tv i just want to show the latest 5/10 episodes that have been seen with a small information Like

Episode
Title
When
(image if possible like on the widgets 
   http://trakt.tv/settings/widgets

```
<a href="http://trakt.tv/user/smirk"><img alt="trakt.tv" src="http://trakt.tv/user/smirk/widget/watched-fanart.jpg" /></a> )
```

So i m a JSON noob and just start to work with apis maybe someone could help me a bit?

Informations about the API could be found here http://trakt.tv/api-docs

Thanks for Helping

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP to dynamically create the image, look into the json_decode function. That can take the API input and convert it to an array for easy use.